# No Activity found exception while sending an image file

Tags: android

I am using the below code to send/share an image file to whatsapp /facebook /bluetooth etc. 
But i am getting the error message **"No Activity found to handle Intent { act=android.intent.action.SEND flg=0x1 (has clip) (has extras) }"**

What i am missing in the code? *( I am expecting options whatsapp /facebook /bluetooth etc. while clicking the button and to send to the selected option)*

```
public void onclick_st(View view) {

    Intent sendIntent = new Intent();
    sendIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    sendIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.fromFile(new File(filepath)));
    startActivity(sendIntent);

}
```

Comment: Put this `shareIntent.setType("image/*");`

Comment: Better yet, use the actual MIME type, not a wildcard. Also, please note that `Uri.fromFile()` will fail on Android 7.0+, once your `targetSdkVersion` rises to 24 or higher. You need to switch to `FileProvider`.

Comment: Thanks. it is working  @RishabhRawat